# How do you LoadUserPofile from within NamePipeServerStream.RunAsClient?

Tags: c#, service, named-pipes, impersonation

I've borrowed some code from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125810/A-complete-Impersonation-Demo-in-Csharp-N) (by Wayne Ye) to pinvoke LoadUserProfile().  My goal is to have a service (currently LOCAL_SYSTEM account) impersonate another user, namely, the user connecting to the named pipe.

Without using LoadUserProfile, my program is working fine for one user, but not for another, and I tracked the user's profile not being loaded.  This is why I try to call LoadUserProfile from within the impersonated context.

When I run the following code, LoadUserProfile() returns false, with error 5, access denied.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a service sample (you need to add your own installer) demonstrating the problem.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestService
{
    public class TestService : ServiceBase
    {
        [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "LoadUserProfileW")]
        public static extern bool LoadUserProfile(IntPtr hToken, ref ProfileInfo lpProfileInfo);
        [DllImport("Userenv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi
            , SetLastError      = true
            , CharSet           = CharSet.Auto
            , EntryPoint        = "UnloadUserProfileW")]
        public static extern bool UnloadUserProfile(IntPtr hToken, IntPtr lpProfileInfo);
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
                components.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
            this.ServiceName = "TestService";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();
        }

        public TestService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("TestServiceSource"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "TestServiceSource", "TestServiceLog");
            }
            eventLog1.Source = "TestServiceSource";
            eventLog1.Log = "TestServiceLog";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                new WaitCallback(o =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //open a named pipe
                        PipeSecurity secu = new PipeSecurity();
                        secu.AddAccessRule(
                            new PipeAccessRule(
                                "Everyone",
                                PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite,
                                System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow)
                            );

                        NamedPipeServerStream pipe = new
                           NamedPipeServerStream(
                              "MyNamedPipe"
                              , PipeDirection.In
                              , 1
                              , PipeTransmissionMode.Byte
                              , PipeOptions.WriteThrough
                                | PipeOptions.Asynchronous
                              , 2048
                              , 2048
                              , secu
                              );

                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server awaiting connection");
                        pipe.WaitForConnection();
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server Connection Request complete");
                        var worker = new ClientWorker(pipe, eventLog1);
                        pipe.RunAsClient(worker.Work);
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server disconnect");
                        pipe.Disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server Exception: " + ex.Message);
                        eventLog1.WriteEntry("Server StackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }));
        }

        public class ClientWorker
        {
            Stream _in;
            EventLog _eventlog;

            public ClientWorker(Stream inStream, EventLog eventLog)
            {
                _in = inStream;
                _eventlog = eventLog;
            }
            public void Work()
            {
                try
                {
                    int len = 0;
                    len += _in.ReadByte() * 256;
                    len += _in.ReadByte();
                    var buffer = new byte[len];

                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("ClientWork Reading");
                    var count = _in.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("ClientWork read complete");
                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("ClientWork received: " + 
                        UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer));

                    var current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(TokenAccessLevels.Read);
                    var name = current.Name;
                    var name2 = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                    var tokenDuplicate = current.Token;

                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("ClientWork user name: " + name2);

                    // Load user profile
                    ProfileInfo profileInfo = new ProfileInfo();
                    profileInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(profileInfo);
                    profileInfo.lpUserName = name2;
                    profileInfo.dwFlags = 1;

                    Boolean loadSuccess = LoadUserProfile(tokenDuplicate, 
                         ref profileInfo);
                    if (!loadSuccess)
                    {
                        var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(err, "LoadUserProfile() failed with error code: " + err);
                    }
                    if (profileInfo.hProfile == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(err, "LoadUserProfile() failed - HKCU handle was not loaded. Error code: " + err);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("Impersonated Client Exception: " + ex.Message);
                    _eventlog.WriteEntry("Impersonated Client StackTrace:\n" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ProfileInfo
    {
        public int dwSize;
        public int dwFlags;
        public string lpUserName;
        public string lpProfilePath;
        public string lpDefaultPath;
        public string lpServerName;
        public string lpPolicyPath;
        public IntPtr hProfile;
    }    
}
```

And here is the client code to call the service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestClient
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
                components.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        } 
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 16);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NamedPipeClientStream _strm = new 
                NamedPipeClientStream(
                    "."
                    , "MyNamedPipe"
                    , PipeDirection.Out
                    , PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough
                    , TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation
                    );

            _strm.Connect();
            string data = "Hello, world!";
            int len = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(data);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
            buffer[0] = (byte)((len >> 8) & 0xff);
            buffer[1] = (byte)(len & 0xff);
            _strm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            _strm.Write(UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data), 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

I have been working on this off and on for over a week.  I hoped someone one could give something more definitive, but instead I will tell what I have found.

Several people on SO have had a similar problem where LoadUserProfile returns Access Denied (5) when calling it after a call to some form of impersonation.  The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says..

> Starting with Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003, the caller must be an administrator or the LocalSystem account. It is not sufficient for the caller to merely impersonate the administrator or LocalSystem account.

So this specifically tells me I can't call LoadUserProfile after I start impersonating another user.  This was confusing because I was thinking I needed to first impersonate the user in order to get a copy of the impersonated user's token to pass to LoadUserProfile. What I mean is, I am not using LogonUser or another API call that takes username and password which gives me a token before calling impersonate, instead I am trying to use the RunAsClient() method of the NamedPipeServerStream which impersonates without having to have the token.

Given what I've learned, how do I get the token then if I can't get it until after I've called RunAsClient?  If I do get the token while impersonating, will the token still be valid when I return (revert back to self)?  And if I wish to fully impersonate a user as if they were logged on (environment, registry access, etc.), what calls must I make?

FYI, in all situations, the connecting users will be either logged in at the console or logged in through Remote Desktop (i.e., the pipe connections from remote clients will be denied).

[EDIT]

I have tried the pinvoke ImpersonateNamedPipeClient to impersonate the client in order to get the token using OpenThreadToken, then calling RevertToSelf and finally calling LoadUserProfile which worked.  I feel like I am reinventing the wheel and that someone has already published a best practice somewhere.

My requirements are to run a certain API as the requesting user from a service.  This 3rd party API apparently initializes itself with internal information specific to the user.  Therefore, I cannot just impersonate in the thread, I will have to launch a new process (correct me if I am wrong).  I would like to avoid loading another EXE by using something like the Unix "fork()", but I can't find a Windows near equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are no answers, I will give what I have found...

LoadUserProfile cannot be called in the impersonated user's context (for normal users).  It is not intended to be.  You would have to load the profile before impersonation, so you must get the user token *before* you call this.  Therefore, RunAsClient() has to be called after you get the user token and after you call LoadUserProfile.

However, you can call RunAsClient() to get the user token and return.  Then you can use the user token in the privileged context to set up the user's environment and then impersonate again.

But since the 3rd party API that I am using performs user-specific initialization in the service's process space, I decided I could not do the work in the windows service (I am open to suggestions otherwise).  Instead, I launched a new process for the impersonated user.

So, my approach was...

1. RunAsClient - to get the token of the impersonated user
2. DuplicateToken - (after returning and reverting to LocalSystem)
3. CreateEnvironmentBlock - (the 3rd party API needed this)
4. Create an Anonymous pipe to communicate with the process
5. CreateProcessAsUser (using the Token, passing the handle to the pipe)

I had to work out issues with flags and parameters along the way, and I plan to update this a little later when I have the time.  I hope this helps someone else, because I had a hard enough time cobbling together the information I needed to do this.